# AngularJS $http error No more request expected

Tags: angularjs, api, jenkins

I m trying to connect my angular front end with Jenkins API.

my service.js

```
angular.module('jenkinsLightApp')
.factory('JenkinsService', function (CONFIG, $location, $http, $httpBackend)        {
    return {
        getJobs: function () {
            var viewParameter = 'All';
            if ($location.search().view) {

                // Set the value of the view query parameter
                viewParameter = $location.search().view;
            }
            // Call Jenkins API
            var promise = $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/pic/view/All/api/json'}).
                then(function successCallback(response) {
                    alert('promise');
                    // Initialize jobs data
                    var data = response.data;
                    var jobs = [];
                 }, function errorCallback(response) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
};
```

I have removed the authentication from jenkins, so angular can be able to connect.
But I have the following error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET      http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/pic/view/All/api/json
No more request expected
$httpBackend@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-  mocks.js:1180:1
sendReq@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8442:1 http/serverRequest@(http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8162:16qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then/wrappedCallbackhttp://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11722:3
```

I have also tried to add

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/pic/).passThrough();
```

that removed the error but I m still unable to dislplay any jenkins job in the browser.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think it would help to see the test spec you have written

Comment: You seem to be using the mock httpBackend, intended to be used in automated tests to mock a backend, to actually connect to a real backend. If that's true, then just don't do that. Remove angular-mocks from your JS files.